# Using MapHttpRoute in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to using the HttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute method in MVC 3. Is this method only designed for MVC 4?

I have spent several hours, but cannot find alternative for MVC 3. How can I achieve the same thing that MapHttpRoute does in MVC 3?

Comment: HttpRouteCollection is used only by WebAPI (in MVC4). what functionality do you want to use in MVC3? there is `RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute()` for use in MVC applications.